# Accelerometer android tiltfunction

Tags: java, android

Im testing out the accelerometer, and trying to make a program that show a text depending on where the user tilts the phone. I have a text that will show when the user tilts the phone right/left and up/down.

I am new to android so if you think this question is stupid, please dont vote down! Tell my what i did wrong with the question so i can do beter next time!

The code below dosent work well, i only get right and top.. and i cant figure out why..

The code for doing this:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // get the change of the x,y,z values of the accelerometer
        deltaX = Math.abs(lastX - event.values[0]);
        deltaY = Math.abs(lastY - event.values[1]);
        deltaZ = Math.abs(lastZ - event.values[2]);

        if (deltaX > 2){
            HideText();
            findViewById(R.id.txtRight).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (deltaY > 2)
        {
            HideText();
            findViewById(R.id.txtUp).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (deltaX < -2)
        {
            HideText();
            findViewById(R.id.txtLeft).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (deltaY < -2) {
            HideText();
            findViewById(R.id.txtUp).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        /*else if ((deltaX > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaY > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaZ > vibrateThreshold)){
            v.vibrate(100);
            HideText();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop shaking me!!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/


    }
```

The code that is comment out i tried to use if the user shakes the phone.. but will save that for later :)

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: oo well sorry.. this code above dont work.. only for right and up..

Comment: You never update last x/y/z.

Comment: I did that first but the code dident work at all then, like this before the first if():
     lastX = event.values[0];
     lastY = event.values[1];
     lastZ = event.values[2];

Comment: Ok, also, keep in mind that Math.abs will never return a negative value.

Comment: Aha, ok but how do i know if the accelerometer goes the other direction?
Man after this course i will stick with C# :P :)

Comment: you could have solved this by debugging your code. run in debug mode, place breakpoints, run step by step, observe the values of the variables.

Comment: i love breakpoints and stepping thro the code.. i do it all the time in VS but in AndroidStudio i cant figure out how to work with breakpoints.. but i will google that now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. Your problem comes from `Math.abs()` - it takes the absolute value of the difference which means it always makes it positive and `deltaX` and `deltaY` will never be <0. Remove `Math.abs()` and it should be OK.

Comment: a good example to use accelerometer in android http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/